# requests.exceptions.SSLError using "requests" package

Tags: python, json

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jung\PycharmProjects\lotto\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Jung\PycharmProjects\lotto\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Jung\PycharmProjects\lotto\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 976, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Jung\PycharmProjects\lotto\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 361, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\Jung\PycharmProjects\lotto\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 377, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\Jung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\Jung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Jung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1108)
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jung\PycharmProjects\lotto\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\Jung\PycharmProjects\lotto\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 724, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\Jung\PycharmProjects\lotto\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 439, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.nlotto.co.kr', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /common.do?method=getLottoNumber&drwNo=832 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1108)')))
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jung/PycharmProjects/lotto/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(get_lotto_numbers(832))
  File "C:/Users/Jung/PycharmProjects/lotto/main.py", line 11, in get_lotto_numbers
    request = requests.get('https://www.nlotto.co.kr/common.do',
  File "C:\Users\Jung\PycharmProjects\lotto\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jung\PycharmProjects\lotto\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jung\PycharmProjects\lotto\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jung\PycharmProjects\lotto\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jung\PycharmProjects\lotto\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.nlotto.co.kr', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /common.do?method=getLottoNumber&drwNo=832 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1108)')))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Do you mind providing the code that is causing this issue?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Could you please include the code that is actually causing the exception?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the question, but if you're getting this exception while doing `requests.get`, you can pass the `verify=False` argument:

`requests.get('https://some.url.com', verify=False)`

That is, of course, if you are certain that it's fine to work with an expired SSL certificate (e.g. as part of a development environment).